# Angularjs - ng-repeat does not reflect changes in property array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My HTML has a loop with ng-repeat:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="item in model.painel track by item.codigoIncidente">
            <strong>{{item.restante.horaMinutoSegundo}}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller has a $interval that decrement horaMinutoSegundo.

```
nihilApp.controller('IncidentePainelController', ['$scope', '$interval', 'Incidente', function ($scope, $interval, Incidente) {

    $scope.model = {
        painel: [],
    };

    var find = function() {
        Incidente.listPainel({pagina: 0}).$promise.then(function (result) {
            $scope.model.painel = result.pagedList;
            $scope.model.totalItems = result.totalGeral;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    };

    var updateTime = function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.painel.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.model.painel[i].status.id === 'E' && $scope.model.painel[i].restante.segundos > 0) {
            var segundos = $scope.model.painel[i].restante.segundos - 1;
            $scope.model.painel[i].restante.horaMinutoSegundo = getHoraMinutoSegundo(segundos);
        }    
        }


    };


    var getHoraMinutoSegundo = function (segundos) {
        var horaMath = Math.floor(segundos / 3600);
        var remMath = Math.floor(segundos % 3600);
        var minutoMath = Math.floor(remMath / 60);
        var segundoMath = Math.floor(remMath % 60);

        var hrStr = (horaMath < 10 ? "0" : "") + horaMath;
        var mnStr = (minutoMath < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutoMath;
        var secStr = (segundoMath < 10 ? "0" : "") + segundoMath;

        return hrStr.concat(":").concat(mnStr).concat(":").concat(secStr);
    };    

    $interval(updateTime, 1000);

    find();

}]);
```

But the {{item.restante.horaMinutoSegundo}} does not update in HTML. Can someone help me with this problem ? Thanks a lot!

https://jsfiddle.net/araraujo/96w3jrrh/

Comment: Did you inject `$interval` in your controller ?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: yes. I injected $interval and no error appears in console

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle/plunkr?

Comment: @Kosmo, the jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/araraujo/96w3jrrh/

Comment: Thanks ! I posted an answer related to your fiddle few seconds ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, but you  have a little mistake in your code.

```
var segundos = $scope.model.painel[i].restante.segundos - 1;
```

You put new `segundos` value into a variable, but you didn't update the one from scope.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/96w3jrrh/1/) is the fiddle with the updated version

Answer (score 0):

> There are two things you need to change

1. inject $interval in your controller

   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
   }
2. Update your model so that it match the with your logic inside for loop. Something like below.

   $scope.model = {
   painel: [{restante : 1 }] }

Comment: I don't how's your model look like

Comment: $scope.model.painel is a json array retrieved from REST. It already has the restante field

Comment: Thanks Dude, Find answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you must add $scope.apply at the end.

```
var updateTime = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.painel.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.model.painel[i].status.id === 'E' && $scope.model.painel[i].restante.segundos > 0) {
        var segundos = $scope.model.painel[i].restante.segundos - 1;
        $scope.model.painel[i].restante.horaMinutoSegundo = getHoraMinutoSegundo(segundos);
    }    
    }

$scope.apply();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Found the gap, replace this line

```
var segundos = $scope.model.painel[i].restante.segundos - 1;
```

> With

```
scope.model.painel[i].restante.segundos = $scope.model.painel[i].restante.segundos - 1;
```